# CSS make li element appear outside of the ul

Tags: css, positioning, z-index

Considering this code:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li class="active">I'm active!</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My .menu div has a 1px black border, and my .active list element has a white background. Now, I want my .active list element to be "outside" of the div, and overlap with the border, hiding it partially with the white background. How is this achievable?

To illustrate what I want;

This is what I have at the moment, coded up;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVZHt.png

And this is what it should look like;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp2k2.png

Comment: Is the active li always the first item in the list?

Comment: No. If you look at the screenshots I added, it's just a menu list, so it depends on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Use relative positioning.

```
.menu li {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

Couple of things to note to make sure that this works:

- The fact that this is on *all* li elements is intentional. If I only put it on the selected one then the selected one would appear shifted down.
- This will only work if the blue background is a part of the `ul` tag and the `li` tag has a transparent background (other than the image of course). Otherwise you might cover up all of the border from the `ul` element.

---

And one more thing (just 'cause). You have this:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
...
</ul>
</div>
```

The ul tag is perfectly capable of having a class by itself. Unless you have a very good reason not to, just do this:

```
<ul class="menu">
    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. About the div around the UL, that's there because the blue background in my screenshot is actually a bar, which goes right through the screen, while the list itself is inside a centered 960px wide wrapper ;)

Comment: @Jean Piere, and that would be the good reason you needed :P.

Comment: @Stargazer712 Ahhh cr*p. That doesn't do anything, except push the li a little further down inside the .menu div. It doesn't appear "on top"  of it, as I wanted.

Comment: It *will* do what you want. Change the top parameter to 100px to see.

Comment: If the problem is that it is not showing up on top, then do this: `.menu ul { position: relative; z-index:1 } .menu li { position: relative; top: 1px; z-index: 2 }`. Other things to try: Make sure that the `li` is actually taking up the entire size of the container. Apply a border to see that this is true. This is what you need to do, and it will work.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. When I change it to 100, it gets hidden somewhere "inside" the menu div. The border is on the div, not the ul, by the way. I need it to overlap with the div, not the ul. Edit; this is what I get when I put a border on; http://cl.ly/7R6T

Comment: I'll say it again. This *IS* what you need to do, and if it doesn't work, that means that you need to keep working with it. Here a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/aYFC2/ .  I can't make it any clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Some CSS black magic for you.

Working example below which should work cross browser. Please ask if you would like an explanation how it works.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xDVC/2/)

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the z-index you're looking for?

```
div.menu li.active { z-index: 99; ... }
```

then you could use negative margins to position it "outside", or better yet nest another element that you can position relatively.